# Ethereum Smart Contract Output -

Tags: contract-design

I have a basic understanding of the Blockchain and its tracking (reconciliation) process. What I like to know is whether the smart contract output can appear as a written document or other printed material?

Everything thing I read on it tends to describe and show the computer language coding process but not the actually useful information output for a layperson to use.

For example: If John agrees, then Rob gets funded, else Rob gets rejected and funds return back to John, etc. However, does it issue a visual view that appears on a webpage that shows "John sent ... XXX" on date, for your YYY., etc.

Just curious to know more. Thanks. Kindly make it simple please.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying, after each interaction with a smart contract you can make it "publish" events on the blockchain. These events will typically include relevant information on the event that triggered them - i.e. an hypothetical `RefundEvent` could have an `amount` field stating the amount of eth that was transferred back, and an `account` field detailing the address to which the money was sent. These are customizable by the developer writing the smart contract. You can then write software that listens to those events and translates them into a log entry in a digital document, a web page update, or whatever else you can do with any other kind of digital data.

Comment: @mamuhalo Thank you, I was hoping to hear just that.